# R grouped-frequency chart

Tags: r, frequency

my data is below

```
 Time   End_Delay_Count
 00:00  4
 00:01  4
 00:02  4
 00:03  8
 00:04  6
 00:05  5
 00:06  8
 00:07  8
 00:08  6
 00:09  6
 00:10  10
 00:11  8
 00:12  17
 00:13  12
 00:14  22
 00:15  20
 00:16  21
 00:17  21
 00:18  33
 00:19  26
 00:20  20
 00:21  24
 00:22  34
 00:23  26
 00:24  31
 00:25  39
 00:26  30
 00:27  30
 00:28  24 
 00:29  37
 00:30  39
```

I want to create a grouped frequncy chart, where in I want duration as variable e.g. If duration is 5 mins then data should summarize as below:

```
00:05  26
00:10  33
00:15  69
00:20  111
00:25  135
00:30  160
```

Comment: Thank you for info.. I was searching for "Grouped frequency chart". What if there is not time interval involved?

Comment: There are a variety of commands and strategies for aggregating data in R. You need to be more specific.